# Incomplete corrupt image upload blob phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, blob

I am currently learning about php and mysql. I am following a few different tutorials and trying to insert and later on display images into my mysql database.
**I do not want to store links to image files in the database**

However, althrough neither phpmyadmin nor sql throwing any errors, the file upload does not work as expected. No matter the size of the file, it only uploads about 75% of it and hence produces corrupt pictures.

Please see the screenshots below that help illustrate the problem.

On the first picture you see me selecting the image IMG_1422 and right next to it the max file size allowed.

On the following picture you see the real file size on the right (1.8) and the inserted filesize of (1.4)

The data type I am using to store the image file is of the type long_blob.

[image: Inserting the pic via phpmyadmin]

[image: Overview of the database after inserting the record]

Here is the part of the mysql.conf that is not commented out.

```
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 10M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 128M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 32M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: Does it work properly if you use a smaller file, say something that's on the order of a 100-200KB? For a few moments of troubleshooting, I wouldn't worry much about the file size displayed since there could be differences in computing the size (1,000 vs 1,024 byte math, bytes vs bits, etc) and would instead focus on the file; try viewing it through phpMyAdmin, what happens? Try downloading it then comparing to the original.

Comment: hi issac thanks for the reply. No filesize makes no difference. I also downloaded a couple of random jpgs form the web just to double check that my Pictures werent corrupt.  If i view the file in phpmyadmin it is also displayed incorrectly.

Comment: If it were some resource limit or timeout, I would expect smaller files to complete, so this is a bit puzzling. What phpMyAdmin, MySQL, and PHP versions are you using? What webserver? Any hints in the webserver error log?

Comment: I am using xampp for Windows 10. Just downloaded the newest package from the Website. Apache webserver, php 5.x  and an InnoDb database. no there is nothing in the error log of the webserver....

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the phpMyAdmin version number listed on their website, but it should be relatively easy for you to find on the main page on the right side it gives a lot of server information, towards the bottom is a heading "phpMyAdmin" with "Version information" following (just above the links to "Documentation," "Wiki," and more).

Answer (score 0):

Ok also this is not a definite answer to my question, i figured out part of the problem and realised that the question is too localised as that it could be answered and help others.

The problem lies with the storage engine innodb.
During the course of adopting the config file to avoid errors such as :

```
The size of BLOB/TEXT data inserted in one transaction is greater than 10% of redo log size. Increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size.
```

I must have inadvertently broken my config file for the inno_db database type.
If i change the database type to MyISAM, all my problems are a thing of the past.

Just wondering now if that has any other consequences?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not the good answers 6 months later...
I had the same probleme today and I just changed in the database (phpMyAdmin) the type too LONGBLOB.

Hope is I can help someone with this!